# 'Property' cannot implement 'Property' because there is no matching property on interface 'IName'

Tags: .net, vb.net, interface

I'm having some very weird issues with interfaces right now.

I have a very simple setup.

In one of my class, I have a `Property` implementing a `Property` from an `Interface`.

In my class it's like:

```
Private _oForm As IForm
Public Property Form As IForm Implements IContainer.Form
    Set(value As IForm)
        Me._oForm = value
    End Set
    Get
        Return Me._oForm
    End Get
End Property
```

Here's the IContainer Interface:

```
Public Interface IContainer

    Property Form As IForm

    Sub OpenScreen(p_oDataKey As DataKey, Optional ByVal p_oOpenScreenProperties As OpenScreenProperties = Nothing)

End Interface
```

It's pretty straightforward isn't it? There's no complex implementation at all, and I can't seem to work it out.

And for the sake of it, right now there's NOTHING inside my IForm:

```
Public Interface IForm

End Interface
```

I always get:

```
Error   2   Class 'BaseContainer' must implement 'Property Form As IForm' for interface 'Common.IContainer'. Implementing property must have matching 'ReadOnly' or 'WriteOnly' specifiers.
```

and

```
Error   3   'Form' cannot implement 'Form' because there is no matching property on interface 'Common.IContainer'.
```

I have like dozens of interfaces like this working throughout my project and I can't believe this simple one can't work! Please give me a hand here :P

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Update your code snippets to show a class named "BaseContainer"

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that another implements icontainer.form or implements iform.form was not added elsewhere in the class.

If you type Implements IContainer, for example, VB will helpfully add implementors to your class. If you change the interface later, you may have leftover references.